# Typescript Error fetching data from firebase and store into array [IONIC]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, variables, ionic-framework

I want to have a function that gets all the data in firebase realtime database and putting it inside an array in order to map in react. I'm getting a TypeScript error and im not sure how to fix it,

Thats the error: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
It occurs on setProducts(Produkte)

and the relavant code:

```
const loadData = async (dbRefName: string) => {
let Produkte: any[] = [];
var dbProduktRef = firebase.database().ref(dbRefName);  
dbProduktRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
  console.log("FireB ", snapshot.val());
  let key;
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    key = child.key || '{}';
    const snapVal =snapshot.val();
    Produkte.push(snapVal[key]);
  });
  setProducts(Produkte)
});  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my code comment below, and perhaps it could be useful for your debugging thought process.

```
const loadData = async (dbRefName: string) => {
        let Produkte: any[] = [];
        var dbProduktRef = firebase.database().ref(dbRefName);
        dbProduktRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
            console.log("FireB ", snapshot.val());
            
            let key;
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    
                key = child.key || '{}'; // [a] This doesn't seem right. What's your intention here?
                const snapVal = snapshot.val(); // [b] Why is this? Since you are alreadying looping through snapshot
                Produkte.push(snapVal[key]); // [c] This is error prone due to [a]. See the above code comment
            });
    
            // [d] I am assuming this is a react hook or some kind of function that updates a state, no?
            setProducts(Produkte); // [e] What is the expected data type of the setProduct paramater?
        });

};
```